# G Drive, recursive list of documents, starting with MyDrive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I've got a script that I'm running under a google sheet for recursively listing documents from MyDrive folders. Works fine.  The key variable is the url for the starting folder. However, I cannot get it to work with MyDrive as the "top" folder. MyDrive does not have the same type of folder id as folders under MyDRive, e.g. 1PVDFLJnUwm_4PhVzZRE6TA2XYr7K8f9H (faked).

The "url" for MyDrive is just this:
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/my-drive
"my-drive" does not work as the key variable for the starting folder.

What is the correct url for starting the recursion with MyDrive as the "top" folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getRootFolder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getrootfolder)

> Gets the folder at the root of the user's Drive.

Comment: Looks right. I somehow broke the script, so I'll confirm your answer after I get it running again.

Comment: Yes, seems to be working.   const folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();